# Regular expression for factor1-1.25/factor2-2.5/

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for **factor1-1.25/factor2-2.5/**
is it correct for this?

```
var regex = /([^\/-])+(-)+(\\d+)+([^\/-])+$/;
```

I don't have any knowledge in regular expressions!
Thanks.

Comment: Is `factor1-1.25` and `factor2-2.5` considered different matches? Or is `factor1-1.25/` a single string, or is `factor1-1.25/factor2-2.5/` the complete string you want matched?

Comment: factor1-1.25 and factor2-2.5 are different matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Here's what your regex does:

```
([^\/-])+  # Match any amount of characters that aren't "/" or "-"
(-)+       # A sequence of "-"s
(\d+)+     # Some of some digits (?!)
([^\/-])+  # Some more characters that aren't "/" or "-"
$      # End of string!
```

You have to modify it to the following:

```
/^(?:[^\/-]+-+\d+[^\/-]*\/)+$/
```

Notable changes:

- Remove the capturing groups - They do not seem to be necessary.
- Anchor for the end of string while matching the literal backslash.
- Anchor for the start of string as well.
- Use quantified groups.

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/cB7gR7/2)